# Carrierwave not uploading file (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I'm having trouble uploading files through Carrierwave. My models are set up so that there are many bottles, and each bottle can have multiple swatches. Each swatch is an image uploaded through Carrierwave. However, the files aren't saving at all. No files are showing up in the directory I want it to save to, and calling `if @bottle.swatches.any?` in the views doesn't show anything.

This is my first time using Rails 4, so I have a feeling my mistake might be due to nooby practices (and not actually Carrierwave). I've looked all over stack, but nothing I've tried is working. What am I doing wrong? Thanks so much in advance!

```
class Swatch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :bottle, dependent: :destroy
  mount_uploader :swatch, SwatchUploader

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :bottle_id, presence: true
end

class Bottle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :swatches
  has_many :favorite_bottles
  has_many :favorited_by, through: :favorite_bottles, source: :user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :swatches
  validates :name, 
    presence: true,
    length:              { in: 1..100 }

end
```

Controllers

```
class BottlesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @bottle = Bottle.new
    @bottle.swatches.build
  end

  def create
    @bottle = Bottle.new(bottle_params)

    if @bottle.save
      redirect_to @bottle
    else
      render 'new'
    end

  end

  #... edit, show, index... etc


  private
    def bottle_params
      params.require(:bottle).permit(:name, :brand, :color, :finish, :swatch, :swatches)
    end
```

swatch_uploader.rb

```
class SwatchUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :file

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

HTML (HAML)

```
= form_for @bottle, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
  - if @bottle.errors.any?
    .alert.alert-danger
      - @bottle.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        = msg
  .col-md-6
    %p
      = f.fields_for :swatches do |swatch|
        = swatch.label :swatch
        = swatch.file_field :swatch
    %p
      = f.label :name
      = f.text_field :name
    %p
      = f.submit 'Submit'
```

In console logs after hitting submit:

```
Started POST "/bottles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-08 10:25:54 -0500
Processing by BottlesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"eOIHJNs6quv2OQQpp2tDn+9+d8rY8oiTjUI/gyp1bn4=", "bottle"=>{"swatches_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"swatch"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fb6aac322c0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/pw/hw3vcmbs3s39dp2l89j0y23r0000gn/T/RackMultipart20131108-97524-dkcjzh>, @original_filename="Malice.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"bottle[swatches_attributes][0][swatch]\"; filename=\"Malice.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}}, "name"=>"sdfsdf", "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

Comment: can you show your bottle_params

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is with your strong params.  Try this:

```
params.require(:bottle).permit({whatever bottle inputs you have},
 swatches_attributes: [{whatever swatch inputs you have, including the picture}])
```

Comment: curly brackets just mean {insert your specific data here}.  Glad I could help!  Good luck with your app!  You may have issues with the update action later on.  Just comment back here if you need help.

Comment: can you post the attributes you included?